# Интерпретировать тип Period при вставке в ORACLE

Tags: python, pandas, oracle

У меня есть dataframe, который я обрабатываю и после привожу к списку, и далее
пытаюсь вставить в Oracle таблицу значения дат с типом PERIOD через executemany
Выдает ошибку

```
cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type Period not supported.
```

Можно ли как то итерпретировать тип Period при вставке, конвертировать в timestamp не вариант, т.к у меня есть даты которые не помещаются в min/max  timestamp (типо 1321-01-01 или 4113-11-23)

Кусок кода с примерным набором данных:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TEST1': [pd.Period("1311-03-11 13:03:12.050000"),pd.Period("1955-11-03 10:06:12.1230000"),pd.Period("4113-11-23 13:22:51.050000"), pd.Period("1512-07-01 10:11:02.123000")]})
lst = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
sql = f"insert into table_name (columns)  values(:1)"
oracle_cursor.executemany(sql, lst)
```

Comment: Добавте в вопрос воспроизводимый пример кода, пример данных и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Вроде как в oracle что date, что timestamp в диапазоне от -4712-01-01 00:00:00  до  9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999. Если тип данных Period не подходит для cx_oracle, то может его поменять на datetime?

Comment: _конвертировать в timestamp не вариант, т.к у меня есть даты которые не помещаются в min/max timestamp_, а почему вы не показали пример таких дат?